# uploading an image and display in browser window

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I have implemented a code in which image is uploaded into the browser and shown as thumbnail. Then it can also be dragged into a canvas area. But when i run it in chrome, it is not opening the window to upload the file. First the image is uploaded, then its thumbnail is created. But it is not working in chrome.

Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Drag Demo</title>
<link href="copy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div style = "border:2px  solid black;">
<canvas id = "canvas" style = "position:relative;width:300px;height:300px;top:0px;left:500px; border:2px  solid black;" ondrop="dropIt(event);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();"> </canvas>    
</div>
<div>
    <input type="file" id="fileElem" accept="image/*" style="display:none" >
    <div id="fileSelect" class="drop-area">Select some files</div>
</div>
    <div id="thumbnail"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function dragIt(event) {
event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id)
};


function dropIt(event) {
  var theData = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  dt = document.getElementById(theData);
  event.preventDefault();
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(dt, 100, 0,dt.width,dt.height);      
};


var count = 0;
var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem");


fileElem.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  var files = this.files
  handleFiles(files)
},false)  


fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    fileElem.click();
  e.preventDefault(); 
}, false);


function handleFiles(files) {  
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
    var file = files[i];  
    var imageType = /image.*/; 

    if(!file.type.match(imageType)){
      console.log("Not an Image");
      continue;
    }
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
    image.file = file;
    thumbnail.appendChild(image)
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (function(aImg){
      return function(e){
        aImg.src = e.target.result;
      };
    }(image))
    image.id = count;
    count++;
    image.draggable = true;
    image.ondragstart = dragIt;
    var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The above code is working in firefox!]

Comment: I can't help you a lot, because I'm on my phone, but try to debug the code. Use alert() or console.log() after every line and see which part is not executing.

Comment: I have already tried! When fileElem.click() executes, it goes to the event and in firefox, a window is opened to select the file. But in chrome, it follows same but window doesn't open up for file select!!!!

Comment: I removed display none from the input. Then it opens the window in chrome. But still after upload, images doesn't appear as thumbnail in chrome while in firefox it is working!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Just run the code on a server and it will work!